# Azure DevOps - Release Calendar?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management

I'm wondering if anyone knows if there is a Release Calendar widget/view in Azure DevOps Services.  Our support team simply wants to see our production releases (successful release pipeline runs) on a calendar so they know when updates to our service has happened.

Note: I looked through the existing widgets and marketplace but nothing stood out so asking here before we evaluate building it.

Update: We presently don't use Boards or Repos in Azure DevOps.  We only use Pipelines so looking for a solution that plays nice with just that but appreciate sharing the other options.

Comment: Does this fit your requirements:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans  (You can create markers to represent releases)

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below sample could help you achieve Release Calendar now? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here thus I could continue to help you:-)

Comment: I'm configuring a couple of the suggestions here to see what would work best.  Will get back to everyone soon!

Comment: @TrevorBrooks doesn't look like this will work.  I failed to mention that we do not use Azure DevOps for Work Items.  Delivery Plans looks like it requires Work Item management in Azure DevOps to be effective.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Release Pipeline Overview widget without install anything in marketplace.
[image]

After you select one release pipeline, this widget will show the names and status in the specific pipeline like below.
[image]
[image]

Then in your release pipeline, click Options and find the Release name format.
[image]

Change the Release name format and add the specifice predefined variable to it.
[image]

This variable will display the current date in you release name. Then you can get the release calendar in the Release pipeline overview widger like below.
[image]

**Addition**

You can refer to here to get more information about pre-defined variable to specify the format mask.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/index?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases

Comment: This ALMOST gets the job done but I'd need something that can just show our production stage.  We have a lot of pre-prod releases that don't make it to prod which quickly pushes down the production releases out of view.  Also, they want the date of the actual production release so giving the release a date doesn't work because it wouldn't necessarily line up with the actual date.

Comment: What about this? Add a Powershell script in or after your production stage. Once a production stage finished, create a work item in your project. You can query these work items to get the work items' create date, and the date value is similar as the line up with the acutal date.

Comment: They just added some filtering functionality on the releases page that lets you show only releases that are currently released. Super useful as we have the same consideration

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can leverage the new Portfolio Plans beta stuff to accomplish this.

Comment: I'll check this out and see how it fits our need.